# Timing issue in map / forEach while waiting for promise

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I have the a timing issue. What's going on is toDataUrl doesn't complete before `chrome.storage.local.get` is called. How can I refactor to have map or some other loop move on once the dataUrl is ready? I've tried async await, changing forEach to maps and vice versa. I've also tried while loops and counters but maybe I'm not implementing it correctly?

To clarify: what needs to happen is the `chrome.storage.local.get` needs to be called once all the loops have fully completed which doesn't currently happen.

To Data Url:

```
    const toDataURL = url => fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result)
        reader.onerror = reject
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
  }))
```

Main Body:

```
app.checkOfflineStorage = function(quotes) {

  let nQuotes = quotes;

  nQuotes.data.map(function(e, idx) {

    if(e.attachments) {
      e.attachments.data.forEach(function(el) {

        if(el.type === 'quote-picture') {

           toDataURL(`https://quotecatalog.imgix.net${el.value}?w=110`).then(function(res) { 

          el.dataURI = res;

        })
    }

  })
}

if(e.title) {
  if(typeof e.title.data.attachments !== 'undefined') {
    var title_attachments = e.title.data.attachments.data;

    title_attachments.forEach(function(el) {

 toDataURL(`https://quotecatalog.imgix.net${el.value}?w=110`).then(function(res) { 

        el.dataURI = res;
      })
    })
  }
}
  })


   chrome.storage.local.get('offlineCache', 


  if (Object.keys(storedQuoteArray).length === 0) {

    console.log(nQuotes)
    chrome.storage.local.set({"offlineCache": nQuotes}, function(res) {});

  } else {


    console.log(nQuotes)
    var combinedArray = storedQuoteArray.offlineCache.data.concat(nQuotes.data)

    combinedArray = combinedArray.slice(0, 100)
    console.log('100', combinedArray)

    chrome.storage.local.set({"offlineCache": {"data": combinedArray}}, function(res) {});
  }

   })
   }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate as to what you are trying to achieve? A mysterious reference to `chrome.set.storage` doesn't ring any bells since it doesn't show up in your code. 
So: What are you trying to achieve? What is the expected behaviour here? and how does the current behaviour differ?

Comment: @deiga I updated the question

Comment: none of your promises are being "waited" for in either the .map (why .map if you dont' return anything) or .forEach "loops"

Comment: Ok @JaromandaX, how can I fix that? I've used both map and forEach

Comment: yes, you have used both, not sure why you bothered with .map if you don't return anything from it (that's just a slower forEach) - fix it, by waiting for the promises to complete ... Promise.all will help

Comment: How can I use promise all?

Comment: [Don't use `forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

A quick example of `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(e.attachments.data.map(function(el) {
    if(el.type === 'quote-picture') {
       return toDataURL(`https://quotecatalog.imgix.net${el.value}?w=110`)
    }
);)
.then(function (resultArray) {
// Handle results array
});
```